# Fax Invitation letter to the consulate for Schengen business visa application?

Tags: visas, france, uk-residents, invitation-letters, conferences

I am a PhD student in the UK, planning to attend a workshop in **France**. In looking up the visa application information, I come to this forum and has known that business visa would be my right choice. While some may recommend a uniform short-stay visa, I am concerned with the academic nature as *"Researchers travelling to perform scientific research"* enjoys a policy of free visa fee, as indicated by the Schengen Visa website.

Now, my question is about the invitation letter. from the website, I find the statement as below:

> Invitation letter. Written by the partner company in the Schengen
>   zone, faxed also to the corresponding consulate. This letter has to
>   appear as an invitation to attend meetings or other relevant events
>   matching trade, industry or work.

I am wondering the meaning *"faxed also to the corresponding consulate"*. Does it mean that the workshop organizer needs to fax/email a copy of the letter to me, and the other to the consulate? It sounds weird. For another, if it does, fax to the France consulate in the UK, or the entrusted visa centre?

Comment: What web site did you find that text on?

Comment: https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/business-schengen-visa/  thanks